# JPA Eclipselink PostgreSQL Query field for Null values

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, postgresql-9.4, glassfish-4.1

I stumbled over a very strange behaviour with JPA Eclipselink and PostgreSQL.

```
create table test(id bigint, name varchar(255))

insert into test values(1, "hello")
insert into test values(2, null)
```

Java EE Entity Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Stateless Bean with simple JPA Query:

```
    TypedQuery<Test> q = em.createQuery("select t from Test t where t.name = :name", Test.class);
    q.setParameter("name", null);
    List<Test> list = q.getResultList();
    for (Test t : list) {
        System.out.println(t.getId() + " " + t.getName());
    }
```

Result:

Aspected: Row with id=2 with null in name field
Current behaviour: No rows returned

When I use "is null" instead of example above in JPA Query. Then I do get something back.

What does JPA do?

```
select * from test where t.name = null
```

should this not be the same as

```
select * from test where t.name is null
```

Comment: Your query contains `t.name = :name` so that's what is sent to the database

Comment: Then for postgresql  "is null" and "= null" is not the same thing?

Comment: No it's not. You can't compare `NULL` with `=` in SQL (this is how SQL was defined) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Found this on PostgreSQL docu page: 

Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.)


https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparison.html

And when I try in pgAdmin with manual written SQL: Same result as in JPA. I don't get a value when using field = null

Comment: Sybase behaves different: 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug89.htm

Comment: Then Sybase doesn't comply with the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL also has the 'is null' comparator that you are required to use to compare to null values.  While some JPA providers can interpret and determine that the value passed into an equality is null, and therefore use "IS NULL" in the generated SQL, this is generally not viable when using parameters when the value can change as it means the statement underneath the query must change as well.

Comment: You are right. But that makes writing one query for null and not null values impossible, if you don't want to increase compexitiy. As I'm used to Sybase this differenciation is new and also feels a bit useless to me. 
I also found out that one can change postgresql configuration that it automatically converts "= null" to "is null"